# How to add an HTML link on a Lightning Communities Page

Tags: apex, lightning, partner-communities

Have a seemingly easy request that I can't find a workable answer to. Trying to add an internal link to an error message thrown on a Lightning Communities page, but so far no luck. FWIW, the code:

```
public static final String ERROR_SUPPORT_OPEN_CASE = 'We are unable to process your request. Please &lt;a href=&quot;/gethelp&quot;&gt;open a case&lt;/a&gt;';
```

---

```
else {
    rw.message = ERROR_SUPPORT_OPEN_CASE.unescapeHtml4();
    rw.isSuccess = false;
    return rw;
}
```

Per various articles, this isn't supported yet in Lightning. Wut.

Any ideas? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: How are you showing this message? You can try lightning:formattedRichText for showing link.

Comment: Can you add more details as what are you using on front-end to show the message? Is it Lightning component or a visualforce page?